# Is it possible to simplify this matrix operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I would like to know if it is possible to simplify this expression, I have tried a lot, but I have not been able to do it.

\begin{equation}\text{diag}(V_{pn}) \text{diag}^{-1}((I-M)V_{pn})\end{equation}

Where $V_{pn}$ is a given variable:

\begin{equation}
 V_{pn} = \begin{pmatrix} V1p \\ V1n \\ \vdots \\ VNp \\ VNn \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I is the identity matrix, and M is an auxiliary matrix given by:

\begin{gather}
    \mathbf{M}=\begin{pmatrix} 
    0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots & \vdots\\
    0 &  0 & \dots & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}\\
\end{gather}

Naturally I-M is a singular matrix; however the variables in $V_{pn}$ with Vp are strictly positive, and with Vn strictly negative. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is ${\rm diag}^{-1}$? You can easily calculate the coordinates of $(I-M)V_{pn}$.